# Strange Log in Apache

Tags: apache, logging

I found in my Apache log something strange in requested URL / method request (I suspect an attempt to hack):

```
\x1b\x95J\xe2h\xa7\xcfj\xe1`\x85R\x1f\x98\x9e\xcf\xdedFM(\xa8\xbcc\xc0P\xd9::e\xed\xaa~L\x88\x19\xca
```

full log line:

```
localhost:80 [REDACTED IP] - - [05/Nov/2015:11:04:05 +0100] "\x1b\x95J\xe2h\xa7\xcfj\xe1`\x85R\x1f\x98\x9e\xcf\xdedFM(\xa8\xbcc\xc0P\xd9::e\xed\xaa~L\x88\x19\xca \xbfs\x7f " 400 226 "-" "-"
```

`localhost:80 [REDACTED IP] - - [05/Nov/2015:07:04:14 +0100] "{\xd8\xc7/ \xef\x02\xbc9~\xdb" 400 226 "`-" "-"

I already saw this kind of code in PHP code to force something like recompiled code to be executed or something like that, it stays obscure in my mind.

- What is this code (language)?
- Can I translate it ?
- Any global info that would help me to understand...

Comment: Here's a similar question with good answers:
[strange code in apache logs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5202901/who-can-decode-this-code%20similar)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that field where you see the "strange code" is where you see the HTTP request that was made to the server, for example "GET / HTTP/1.1".

That log line means that someone connected to your server and send that "strange code" instead of a normal HTTP request, it could be a exploit for your current server or trying to exploit the shellshock bug.

A good thing to do now is try to check if there are some known bugs for your current Apache version, and test your system agains shellshock exploit.

- How to reproduce it: printf "\x1b\x95J\xe2h\xa7\xcfj\xe1`\x85R\x1f\x98\x9e\xcf\xdedFM(\xa8\xbcc\xc0P\xd9::e\xed\xaa~L\x88\x19\xca \xbfs\x7f " | nc -n -i 1 www.website.com 80
- How to get the converted code: printf "\x1b\x95J\xe2h\xa7\xcfj\xe1`\x85R\x1f\x98\x9e\xcf\xdedFM(\xa8\xbcc\xc0P\xd9::e\xed\xaa~L\x88\x19\xca \xbfs\x7f "

Comment: thanks but in fact i am lore looking on how to reproduce it, and be able to get the converted code to know what was tried. About my apache security all is ok.

Comment: I just edited the reply with the answer to your comments

Comment: thanks, there is something strange ` won't pass on the printf